# How to select all uitableview cells on button click

Tags: ios, uitableview

I am making an app in which i am using buttons in the form of checkboxes in uitableview cell.i am changing images on that checkbox select and unselect state. now i want that when i click on another button then  all the cells of table view will be select and image of all the checkboxes of cells will changed? how it can done below is my sample code

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return self.lblArray.count;

}



- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *tableviewidentifier = @"cell";
    TablecellTableViewCell *cell= [self.tblvie dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:tableviewidentifier];

    if(cell==nil)
    {
        cell = [[TablecellTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:tableviewidentifier];
    }

    cell.lblImage.layer.cornerRadius=3.0f;
    cell.lblImage.layer.borderWidth=1.0f;
    cell.backgroundColor=[UIColor colorWithRed:(245/255.0) green:(245/255.0) blue:(245/255.0) alpha:1];



    if ([self.checkimageArray containsObject:[self.lblArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]])
    {

        [cell.buttonCheckbox setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"check_box_ok.png"]
                     forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    }
    else
    {
        [cell.buttonCheckbox setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"uncheck.png"]
                             forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    }

    cell.buttonCheckbox.tag=indexPath.row;
    [cell.buttonCheckbox addTarget:self action:@selector(checkButton:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];





    cell.lblText.text=[self.lblArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    return cell;

}

-(IBAction)checkButton:(UIButton *)sender
{
    CGPoint buttonPosition = [sender convertPoint:CGPointZero toView:self.tblvie];
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tblvie indexPathForRowAtPoint:buttonPosition];


    if ([self.checkimageArray containsObject:[self.lblArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]) {
        [self.checkimageArray removeObject:[self.lblArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
        self.titleLabel.text=@"";

           }
    else {
        [self.checkimageArray addObject:[self.lblArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
                self.titleLabel.text=[self.lblArray objectAtIndex:sender.tag];

    }
    [self.tblvie reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimationFade];


}
```

and here is my button in which i click then all the cells of tableview will select and images of all the cells will changed but it is not working

```
- (IBAction)selectbtns:(id)sender {
    static NSString *tableviewidentifier = @"cell";
    TablecellTableViewCell *cell= [self.tblvie dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:tableviewidentifier];
    [cell.buttonCheckbox setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"check_box_ok.png"]
                         forState:UIControlStateNormal];


   }
```

Comment: r u tried after this **[cell.buttonCheckbox setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"check_box_ok.png"]
                         forState:UIControlStateNormal];**    line add [yourtableview reloaddata]

Comment: yeah tried but "Could not load the "" image referenced from a nib in the bundle with identifier "com.xxx.whyq.checkboxwithTableview"
"

Comment: clean and run again once

Comment: good what the result u need finally

Comment: i want to select all the cells on button click.

Comment: select the all the cells or all check boxes

Comment: i want both that when i click on btn then all cells will be select and all the images of checkboxes will be changed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
NSMutableArray *totalcheckmarkArray; //add on NSMutablearray in globally

- (void)viewDidLoad    {

totalcheckmarkArray =[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

 for (int i=0; i<[self.lblArray count]; i++) // Number of Rows count
{
 [self.totalcheckmarkArray addObject:@"NO"];
}

}



-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{

static NSString *tableviewidentifier = @"cell";
TablecellTableViewCell *cell= [self.tblvie dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:tableviewidentifier];

if(cell==nil)
{
    cell = [[TablecellTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:tableviewidentifier];
}

cell.lblImage.layer.cornerRadius=3.0f;
cell.lblImage.layer.borderWidth=1.0f;


if(![[self.totalcheckmarkArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isEqualToString:@"NO"])
{

    [cell.buttonCheckbox setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"check_box_ok.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

}

else if ([self.checkimageArray containsObject:[self.lblArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]])
{

    [cell.buttonCheckbox setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"check_box_ok.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

}
else
{
    [cell.buttonCheckbox setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"uncheck.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}

cell.buttonCheckbox.tag=indexPath.row;
[cell.buttonCheckbox addTarget:self action:@selector(checkButton:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

cell.lblText.text=[self.lblArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

return cell;
 }
```

**selectAll Checkbox**

```
- (IBAction)selectbtns:(id)sender {
   for (int i=0; i<[self.lblArray count]; i++)
 {

[totalcheckmarkArray replaceObjectAtIndex:i withObject:@"YES"];

 }

[self.tblvie reloadData];


 }
```

**DeselectAll Checkbox**

```
-(IBAction)deselectall_btnclick:(id)sender
{
  for (int i=0; i<[self.lblArray count]; i++)
 {

[totalcheckmarkArray replaceObjectAtIndex:i withObject:@"NO"];

 }

[self.tblvie reloadData];

}
```

Comment: an exception Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty array'

Comment: i changed this line in viewdidLoad **[totalcheckmarkArray replaceObjectAtIndex:i withObject:@"NO"];** try this

Comment: same exception is coming

Comment: just wait i cheek and tell to u

Comment: what is checkimageArray ?

Comment: @RaviJSS -- it is an temp array hold the selection index

Answer (score 1):

I can think of two possible solutions. If the following line works in cellForRowAtIndexPath:

```
if ([self.checkimageArray containsObject:[self.lblArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]) {

    [cell.buttonCheckbox setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"check_box_ok.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

}
```

Then just add all the images to `self.checkimageAray` and then reload the table through `[self.tblvie reloadData]`.

If there is a reason you don't want to reload the table, you could do the following, which will loop through all the cells in the table and execute the changes to each cell:

```
for (int section = 0; section < [self.tblvie numberOfSections]; section++) {
    for (int row = 0; row < [self.tblvie numberOfRowsInSection:section]; row++) {
        NSIndexPath* cellPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:row inSection:section];
        TablecellTableViewCell *cell= [self.tblvie  cellForRowAtIndexPath:cellPath];
        [cell.buttonCheckbox setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"check_box_ok.png"]
                     forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
}
```

I tend to iterate over every cell when I wish to make a change with an animation. If say you want to animate the checking of the box, the simplest way would be to place the animation block in the iteration of the cells.

If you wish to then unselect a cell, you could do the following:

```
for (int section = 0; section < [self.tblvie numberOfSections]; section++) {
    for (int row = 0; row < [self.tblvie numberOfRowsInSection:section]; row++) {
        NSIndexPath* cellPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:row inSection:section];
        TablecellTableViewCell *cell= [self.tblvie  cellForRowAtIndexPath:cellPath];
        [cell.buttonCheckbox setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"uncheck.png"]
                         forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
}
```

Please note that this is not changing your `checkimageArray`. While the cells are being displayed as selected, all of the images are not in your `checkimageArray`, and of corse with my solution for unselecting the cell, the images will not be removed from the checkimageArray either.

I would suggest adding all the objects from `self.lblArray` to `checkimageArray` where you place the code to set the cells highlighted and remove all objects from `checkimageArray` when you deselect them all. An example of how to add all images to the array is show in the other answer bellow.

Comment: ok this is for select cells.. now what can i do to unselect them all ??? for solution 2

Comment: I updated my answer with a solution for unselecting the cells. Like I stated in my updated answer, I stress that this is not doing anything with the array of selected images. This means that you are simply displaying the images as selected but not actually selecting them behind the scenes. This would cause problems when you wish to do something with the selected images. Like I suggested, it is very simple to deal with the arrays as well as the appearance of the cells. I would be happy to help with that if need be.

Answer (score 0):

You can do .

```
- (IBAction)selectbtns:(id)sender 
{
     self.checkimageArray = [NSArray arrayWithArray:self.lblArray];
     [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

Comment: what is that warning?